# What is alternative for MultibyteToWideChar and WideCharToMultiByte functions in .NET?

Tags: .net, unicode, encoding

I am trying to migrate a code from VC++ to .net. VC++ code uses MultibyteToWideChar and WideCharToMultiByte functions provided by WinAPI. I tried using System.Text.Encoding class in .NET but it is not working for all encodings. Is there any other way to do this conversion? What is wrong in below code snippet?

Here is my C# code:

```
public static string MultiByteToWideChar(string input, int codepage)
    {
        Encoding e1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(codepage);
        Encoding e2 = Encoding.Unicode;

        //byte[] source = e1.GetBytes(input);

        byte[] source = MBCSToByte(input);

        byte[] target = Encoding.Convert(e1, e2, source);

        return e2.GetString(target);
    }
public static string WideCharToMultiByte(string input, int codepage)
    {
        Encoding e1 = Encoding.Unicode;
        Encoding e2 = Encoding.GetEncoding(codepage);

        byte[] source = e1.GetBytes(input);

        byte[] target = Encoding.Convert(e1, e2, source);

        return Encoding.GetEncoding(codepage).GetString(target);

    }
private static byte[] MBCSToByte(string s)
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[s.Length];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (char c in s)
            b[i++] = (byte)c;
        return b;
    }
```

MultiByteToWideChar is working only for codepage 1255 and not for 866

WideCharToMultiByte is not working for codepage 1251.

Comment: What isn't working and why are you using C++ function names for something **completely** different? There's nothing wrong with `Encoding`. It can convert anything from one encoding to another provided you use the correct codepages. Wrapping it up in other functions simply ensures you'll get the conversions wrong

Comment: To summarize - *what* did you want to convert? 1255 to Unicode? 1255 to 866? The exact same code would work in any case

Comment: .NET strings are Unicode *always*. Are you trying to fix a mangled string perhaps? There are no multibyte or wide strings. If you want to convert a string to a 1255 byte array just use `Encoging.GetEncoding(1255).GetBytes(someString);`. If you want to get a Unicode string from a 1255 array, use `Encoging.GetEncoding(1255).GetString(someString);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiByteToWideChar()` converts encoded bytes (NOT characters!) to Unicode characters.

`WideCharToMultiByte()` converts Unicode characters to encoded bytes (NOT characters!).

In .NET, the `string` type is always a sequence of Unicode characters (in UTF-16 byte encoding).  So using `string` to hold encoded bytes is just plain wrong.

In your `MultiByteToWideChar()` function, you are *assuming* that the input `string` contains Unicode characters that are 16-bit representations of codepage-encoded 8-bit bytes.  You are translating the Unicode characters as-is to a `byte[]` array, then converting that *assumingly* codepage-encoded array to a UTF-16 `byte[]` array, and then you are converting that to a UTF-16 `string`.  This will work fine **if and only if** the initial assumption is true to begin with.  Which is usually not the case, unless your input was corrupted to begin with.

In your `WideCharToMultiByte()` function, you are converting the input `string` to a UTF-16 `byte[]` array, then converting that array to a codepage-encoded `byte[]` array.  So far so good (though you could just use `Encoding.GetBytes()` to go from the UTF-16 `string` directly to the codepage-encoded `byte[]` without using `Encoding.Convert()` at all).  But then you are using the same codepage to convert the codepage-encoded `byte[]` array back to a UTF-16 `string`, thus un-doing everything you had done.  The output `string` will be the same value as the input `string` (provided the specified codepage supports all of the Unicode characters in the input `string`, otherwise you will have data loss during the first codepage conversion).

That being said, the correct code should look more like this instead:

```
public static string MultiByteToWideChar(byte[] input, int codepage)
    {
        return Encoding.GetEncoding(codepage).GetString(input);
    }
public static byte[] WideCharToMultiByte(string input, int codepage)
    {
        return Encoding.GetEncoding(codepage).GetBytes(input);
    }
```

Don't use a `string` to hold encoded bytes, use an actual `byte[]` array instead.

Comment: Code that I am writing is part of CLR stored procedures. I am passing in input to this CLR storeed procedures from SQL stored procedures. Input passed is of type varchar and nvarchar. What should be done in SQL stored procedures to pass in input as byte array instead of string. Following is sql code which is calling multibyte to unicode function with converted unicode bytes as out parameter.  `declare @input varchar(2000)
declare @output varbinary(4000)
declare @outputup nvarchar(2000)
set @input ='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXŽƒŽ Š€€—…‰‘’‚€ Ž '
exec cp2u @input, 866, @output OUTPUT
`

Comment: And expected output for this is 'ОГО КАЗНАЧЕЙСТВА ПО'

Comment: Why are you dealing with character encodings manually at all?  Let the SQL database handle that for you, based on declared charsets and collations of the fields involved.

Answer (score 1):

`string` is a string of characters, not a byte stream. You already lost when you wrapped your binary data in a `string`.

If you want proper conversions between encodings, make sure to use `byte[]`. `string` already gives meaning to those bytes. .NET's `string` isn't the same thing as C's `char*`. Keep `string` for `string`s, and use `byte[]` for persistence, networking etc.